# Problem in Inserting record to Sql Server 2008 by Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert some record into my Sql Server 2008 data base using javascript. But not happening.My code

```
try
        {

            var ConProv = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");             
            var ConnString ="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SerevrName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=text;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx;";
            ConProv.Open(ConnString);
            var RecSet = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");              
            var SqlSt = "insert into tbl_test(Col1,Col2) Values('Val1','Val2')";

            RecSet.ExecQuery(SqlSt, ConProv);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
          txt="Error description: " + err.description;    
          alert(txt);
        }
```

Error Message: Object does not suport this method or property..

What is that I am missing...

N.B. I know it is not a good approach of acessing DB but I am experimenting this an learning.

Comment: I got the answer ConProv.Execute(SqlSt, ConProv);

Answer (score 0):

Search for `ADODB` and `OLEDB` instead of javascript. Try:

```
try {
  var ConProv = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");             
  var ConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SerevrName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=text;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx;";
  ConProv.Open(ConnString);
  var SqlSt = "insert into tbl_test(Col1,Col2) Values('Val1','Val2')";
  var RecSet = ConProv.Execute(SqlSt);
  ConProv.Close();
}
catch(e) {
  alert("Error description: " + e.description);
}
```

To have more control over parameters for SQL-commands, is more flexible to use `ADODB.Command` and `Execute()` method of `ADODB.Command`